# Can I use Chromecast to cast what I see in my Windows 7 laptop's webcam?

Tags: windows-7, webcam, chromecast

I have two kids at home and sometimes, they do something cute while I am in the room. Calling others into the room spoils the moment. But if I have my laptop in the room, I can try casting it up on the TV using my chromecast. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see your webcam in chrome on your desktop, then you can mirror that tab and cast it to your TV

Comment: This answer triggered few searches and I have found such a chrome app. Will confirm if things are working with chromecast.